# Unit testing for a PHP file

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, unicode

I need to create a test file for this code which I am going to upload.

```
// Create connection

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {

    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {

    //echo "<Strong>Connection Successful</Strong>", "<br>" ;
}
?>
```

Could you please help me create a testing file for this php code?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by create a test file, what are you trying to test?

Comment: please Explain Your question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say was that i have to unit test this code which i have got, i do not know how to create the file which i have to use to unit test this.

Comment: Can anybody help me please?